# Windows 7 taskbar: How to uncombine only some icons?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

For most applications, like Explorer Windows, Browsers, etc. the default automatic grouping of Taskbar buttons is really appropriate, avoids opening unnecessary additional windows, and keeps everything much more organized.

However, since I installed Windows 7, I've been annoyed by the fact that there are some applications which would benefit by staying ungrouped, even if the rest of the applications continue to follow the default "Always Combine" behavior.

For example, with this automatic grouping behavior, all Windows Live Messenger chat windows are also grouped (of course), but that means you have to click TWO times EVERY TIME you want to get to one specific chat window. (or similarly, to wait till the taskbar preview comes up and then click). Additionally, the taskbar button of lights up whenever there's a new message/feedback from any of the chat windows, but there´s no way to quickly know from which one of the open chat windows is this feedback coming.

It would be great to keep them separated, so that each has its own Taskbar button, while the rest of the Taskbar buttons would stay grouped.

Is there any way to do this ?

PS: Took this text from [here](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/1560) since it perfectly describes what I am trying to do.

Comment: The quick answer is you can't. At least not nativly in Win7, where it's all or none, and I know of no 3rd party utils (yet?). I Bumped your question, as I have felt the pain of which you speak, and I hope someone has a better 'answer'. :)

Answer (score 0):

[videoinpicture](http://videoinpicture.wikidot.com/) might be worth a look. It treats taskbar thumbnails as separate movable, resizeable windows. May be a bit dramatic for your purposes, but it should be able to do the job. It's also cool enough to be worth playing around with.